# Registering DLL File when Opening an Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel, dll

I would like to offer the user an opportunity to create a reference to a `.tlb` type library (if non-existent) when they open the macro-enabled Excel workbook.

I have the following subroutine (in VBA), which does works when either fired from a button, or run by pressing the green triangle button in the VBA editor:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim isDLLReferenced As Boolean
    isDLLRegistered = False

    For Each ref In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References
        If Right(LCase(ref.FullPath), 7) = LCase("qms.tlb") Then
            isDLLReferenced = True
            GoTo OutIf
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ref

OutIf:
    If isDLLReferenced = False Then GoTo MessageBox
    GoTo OutSub:

MessageBox:
    Dim question As Integer
    question = MsgBox("A dll file needs to be isDLLReferenced on your 
    computer in order for this template's macros to function", vbYesNo + 
    vbQuestion,  "")
    If question = 7 Then GoTo OutSub

    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Reference\qms.tlb"
    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile filepath

OutSub:
End Sub
```

A reference is not however created if this code is placed in the Workbook_Open event as illustrated above.

The message box appears on opening the workbook, but a reference is not made to the type library.

My question is: How do I programmatically create a reference to the `.tlb` on opening the workbook? (can this be done?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine other than `ActiveWorkbook`, you should use `Thisworkbook`. Also you can omit `GoTo OutIf`. You may also need to check if "Trust access to the VBA project object model" ticked in Trust Center on other systems.

Comment: Even on the same computer, a reference is made to the `.tlb` IF this code it is attached to a button and the button is clicked... but, a reference to the `.tlb` is NOT successfully created if this code is executed as part of the `Workbook_Open` event. I am trying to create a reference to the `.tlb` automatically, when the workbook is opened.